# How to read images using csv in python

Tags: python, csv, image-processing

I have a csv file that contains three columns namely (image file names, labels(in form of 0,1...), and class names). While another folder contains all the images. I want to read the images using this csv file and use them further for the task of image classification using deep learning models on python.

Comment: And what code do you have so far?

Comment: Kindly refrain from cluttering your questions with irrelevant conversational stuff like intros & thanks (edited out).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path

df = pd.read_csv('path_to_csv.csv')
path = Path('path/to/img/dir')  # relative path is OK
dataset = df.apply(lambda file_name, label:
                     return (cv2.imread(path/file_name), label),
                   axis=1)
dataset = np.asarray(dataset)
```

Now you'll have dataset that is a numpy matrix with images as column 1 and labels as column 2

I'm using OpenCV to import image. Of course you can use others like pillow too, but [OpenCV is faster than pillow](https://www.kaggle.com/vfdev5/pil-vs-opencv/data#Fast-benchmark:-Pillow-vs-OpenCV)

Comment: No need to put staff in the comments that should be in the text of the answer (edited).

Comment: You mean this `#relative path is OK`?

Comment: No, I mean the last sentence I moved out of the comments and into the text proper; `#relative path is OK` is OK as a comment there.